# How to prevent sending multiple requests to Firestore from React-Native app?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have an app which will be used by many users, and sometimes they will post to the same document at the same time, how will Firebase handle that. Is there a way that I can prevent that to happen?

My scenario is like this: There is a restaurant where you can order food but there is a limited amount, so let's say 5, and there are 10 users posting to that document at the same time, how can I prevent this happening? P.S. I am using listeners in RN app so it checks all the time for changes in amount but what if the users are faster than the updates in the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to control multiple concurrent writes, you should use a transaction to make sure that each client does not overwrite what other clients are doing.  The transaction will ensure that only one client can write to a document at a time.  In your transaction, you can check if some document field is at a limit that should not be exceeded, then fail the transaction if it would be exceeded.

Read the [documentation on transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to better understand how this works.`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, I just implemented a batched operation now. I had to write to 3 documents at once, so this way I am doing it properly.

Comment: can you explain this once again coz I did not understand: "In your transaction, you can check if some document field is at a limit that should not be exceeded, then fail the transaction if it would be exceeded"

Comment: In your transaction handler, you can check the contents of the document to determine if the write operation that the user wants to do is valid (all your limits are OK).  If it's not valid, then you can simply not perform the write, and fail the transaction.  If you fail the transaction, you can write more code to detect that and present some information to the user about what went wrong.

Comment: ahh such as the limited amount of "Food discounts" for example. because that number is being updated constantly from the db and I am listening to it for changes, and validating based on that, but what if the number goes to 0 in the exact moment when another user is commiting? So in this case I can use what you said right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  If you have another question about how transactions work, please ask a new question and explain what's not working the way you expect.

Comment: I want to check if the amount of items in a collection is bigger than 0. If it is, commit to another collection and if not, fail transaction. Is this something I can achieve with what you explained earlier?

Comment: Yes, you will have to maintain a count of documents in another document using a transaction.

Comment: ok, however, why can't I just check from the app if the amount of fetched collection is bigger then 0? Why do I need to create another document which keeps count of another document?

Comment: Because, as you said, multiple clients could be writing the collection simultaneously, and you can't trust that nothing changed between the latest read and the next write.

Comment: is this what I should use: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters  to do that or just do it with a transaction(check if collection > 0 then post)

Comment: Do whatever meets the needs of your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept of: "Accept or Reject Queries"

Your security rules can also accept or reject queries based on their constraints. The request.query variable contains the limit, offset, and orderBy properties of a query. For example, your security rules can deny any query that doesn't limit the maximum number of documents retrieved to a certain range:

```
allow list: if request.query.limit <= 5;
```

In addition you should consider using [cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions) instead of updating the value directly from client side. 
To be more clear you can call functions via HTTP requests.

Comment: Unfortunately, security rules aren't really going to help protect against multiple concurrent writes from different clients, and `request.query.limit` doesn't at all address the stated issue.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am a bit confused about this Cloud function, it sounds the same as onSnapshot listener in the client app. Isn't it doing the same thing?

Comment: @bmm Don't bother with Cloud Functions here.  It's not necessary.  Use a transaction on the client as I describe in my answer.

Comment: @bmm To be more clear you can call functions via HTTP requests: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events

Comment: @OronBen-David why should I use functions instead of transactions and batches?

Comment: Transaction and batches are basically the same.

Transactions are good for locking documents, if you execute them from the backend, you can make sure that the values you read at the beginning of the operation are still pristine, it hasn't changed. From the client, this is not 100% the same, after the operation is complete, it will sanity check this the initial doc and if it changed, it will retry the operation with the new data.

So you can use transaction on cloud and it will be the best solution for you.